# How do I make a recursive incremental algorithm?

Tags: python

I want to make a recursive incremental algorithm in python that given an array of non-zero real numbers, it should give me a subarray with the highest product of consecutive elements. For example: array = [1, 2, 3, 0.5, 4, 5, 6] the answer should be [4, 5, 6] = 120. Does anyone know how to make that algorithm?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Sorting the array won't work as it ruins order, which is very important in this case.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos: emphasis on "product of **consecutive elements**"...

Comment: Q: can there be negative numbers?

Comment: also, `prod([2, 3, 0.5, 4, 5, 6])` is larger than `prod([4, 5, 6])`...

Comment: Wha code have you tried? What output are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to answer what looks like a school assignment.  However, I'll give you hints.

You can loop through a list may ways.  The following simple way uses an integer, i, to let know you know your position.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 0.5, 4, 5, 6]

# How many many times do you need loop?
# I'm not going to give you the answer; 
# you should be able to figure it out.
# Hint: use the len() function.
num_loops = 0  # <- change 0 to correct number.

# Hint, result must be <= than the smallest item in array.
result = 1000 # <- replace 1000 with correct value

for i in range(num_loops):
    # check your product here
    product = 0  # replace with correct equation.  Hint: use list slicing.
    if product > result:
        result = product
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are strictly positives, then the problem can be solved in linear time, using the [Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem): just take the `log` of all numbers and find the maximum sum subarray. The corresponding subarray (with the same indices) is your answer.

So, to elaborate:

```
def max_product_subarray(x):
    sum_, i, j = max_subarray(np.log(x))
    prod = np.exp(sum_)
    return prod, i, j
```

Where `max_subarray()` is exactly the code given for the [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm) given on the Wikipedia page.

Example:

```
max_product_subarray([1, 2, 3, 0.5, 4, 5, 6])
# out:
(360.0, 1, 7)
```

**Performance**:

This will blow out of the water almost any sort of recursive algorithm (all naive ones will be `O(n^2)`). Here is a test for you:

```
x = 1 - np.random.uniform(size=int(1e6))  # strictly positive numbers

%timeit max_product_subarray(x)

# out:
849 ms ± 103 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Note**:

You can also use numba's `@njit` to decorate `max_subarray`, and then the timing above (1 million elements) drops to:

```
38.7 ms ± 1.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you are allowed to use libraries such as numpy, so I only used plain Python. Also, I still think this is a school project and we shouldn't be giving you solutions, but since everyone has done so, here it is:

Edit: This is now O(n) out of courtesy to @PierreD. ;-)

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 0.5, 4, 5, 6] 
list2 = [4, 5, 6, 0.5, 1, 2, 3] 
list3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.5, -4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 2]
array = list1

iters = len(array)-1
result = 0
product = array[0]
items = []
start_idx = end_idx = 0

for i in range(iters):
    next_idx = i+1
    if (array[i]+1 == array[next_idx]):
        end_idx = next_idx
        product *= array[end_idx]
        if (product > result):
            items = array[start_idx : end_idx+1]
            result = product
    else:
        start_idx = end_idx = next_idx
        product = array[start_idx]
        if (product > result):
            result = product
        
print items , "=" , result
```

The results are:

```
list1: [4, 5, 6] = 120
list2: [4, 5, 6] = 120
list3: [7, 8, 9] = 504
```

Example online: https://rextester.com/HFMSYM52497

Comment: `prod([2, 3, 0.5, 4, 5, 6]) = 360` is higher.

Comment: @PierreD: what do you mean higher? higher to what? OP wants the product of the 3 highest consecutive numbers... It's fairly straighforward.

Comment: where do you see the restriction to "three consecutive" elements?

Comment: Actually, OP didn't say 3! I just assumed from the example he gave. I'll update the answer!

Comment: @PierreD: I din't realize OP is after performance.... Where did you get that idea?

Comment: it's like the "pursuit of happiness"; I always take this consideration as self-evident.

Comment: @PierreD: In that case, let's multi-thread! :-P jk!

Comment: Do try. if you find something faster than Kadane's algorithm on a single core, then I'll upvote whatever you come up with. I also updated my answer to indicate the timing of it when decorating `max_subarray` with `@njit` (from numba). 1 million elements: 39ms...

Comment: No way I'm investing that much time on a SO question. :-P Maybe over xmas holidays.